# In Visual Studio, how can I change the highlight-setting(s) for @{...} bits in *.cshtml files and the like

Tags: visual-studio, razor, syntax, settings

The default highlight-settings render @{ } with a yellow background which looks like a eye-sore if the dark theme is applied in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting which controls how @{...} bits are highlighted is called "HTML Server-Side Script" and it's located under:

Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor -> HTML Server-Side Script

[image]